# Execute R commands from a shell script

Tags: linux, r, shell

I need to Run R interpreter within a shell script an issue some predefined R commands through the shell script. Is this possible?

Right now I have a shell script as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting R"

R
```

This starts an interactive R shell. Now I need to issue some R commands using the same shell script. any ideas?

Comment: `R -e "some_r_functiion();  and_another_function()"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *here document*:

```
... bash stuff
...
/usr/bin/R --no-save << EOT
x<-2*pi*(0.1*(0:10))
print(cbind(x,sin(x)))
quit("no")
EOT
...
... bash stuff
```

Comment: plotting doesn't seem to work with this approach. any idea on how I could make plotting also work?